# Write data into mogoDB using mirth connect

Tags: mongodb, mirth, hl7-fhir

I am using mirth connect to for fhir data, i am able to separate the data into separate variables but don't know how to store into mongoDB as database writer doesn't have any mongoDB option. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use the DB connection through Javascript, try using the below script this is a basic connectivity.

```
var mongoClient = new Packages.com.mongodb.MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
var database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mongoDB");
var collection = database.getCollection("testDB");
```

By default, mongoDB listens in the port 27017. And If you are parsing FHIR then you may need to store entire resource as JSON.

you can append the values in the JSON data using `.append` function and insert them into your db. I hope this code helps.

Comment: Is there any way that i can write fhir data into mongoDB with the patient relation with other resources? and thanks for the answer.

Comment: we can parse the incoming JSON data and put that inside MongoDB collections. To write a complete FHIR data (JSON) I haven't tried it.But logically it should be achievable as well. Please post if there is any issue you are facing. Let me also try from my end.

Comment: Thanks Vibin. I will try that. Can you answer my new question [**Change HTTP URL for FHIR Listener**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033048/how-to-change-http-url-in-fhir-listener-while-using-mirth-connect)

Answer (score 0):

Use *JavaScript Writer* or, even better, *Channel Writer* destination and code everything as a transformer step(s).