# How to change HTTP URL in FHIR Listener while using mirth connect?

Tags: http, hl7-fhir, mirth

I am trying to use the **FHIR Listener extension** in mirth connect. I want to use a sample FHIR server to test the process but i am not able to change the **HTTP URL** in **FHIR Listener Settings**. Is there any way I can change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot change the URL of either HTTP url or FHIR listener url. It will always remain localhost. If you are trying read a sample data from the any test server try as below:

- Go to the HTTP sender
- select GET and paste the URL there test the connection.
- deploy the channel and send some RAW data if your URL is correct you will get the response in Mirth.
- In destination under navigate to "EDIT RESPONSE" portion and type the following to consume the response and print it (or) manipulate the response.

> ```
>   var ResponseMessage = response.getMessage();
>  logger.info(ResponseMessage)
> ```